# Rails 3.0 beta & JS Helpers with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the release notes for Rails 3.0 beta it says:

> "Unobtrusive JavaScript helpers with drivers for Prototype, jQuery"

So how do I setup Rails 3 to use jQuery then? It still loads all the Prototype libraries by default.

I took this to mean that Rails 3 has built in functionality similar to the jRails plugin, but maybe I'm misunderstanding :)

Also, as a bonus question, if I am using Prototype is there a way to get Rails to load the minified versions, and even better a single concatenated JS file to cut down on http requests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Rails 3 app, just pass along the `-J` param as well:

```
$ rails app_name -J
```

This will skip over including the Prototype libraries. Now, all you need to do is drop the latest `jquery.js` file into the `public/javascripts` directory. Once you do that, you'll also need the jQuery version of the `rails.js` file. You can get that here:

http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

EDIT: You need to include these files in the top of your layouts to gain the functionality. You can do this by:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "rails" %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, thats the answer I was looking for :) Thanks.

I think I assumed there would be config for this, and also a config to use minified versions for deployment purposes. Seems like thats standard practice and something Rails should do as standard. Why does it include un-minified prototype to begin with!

Answer (score 1):

Unobtrusive JS doesn't refer to the PrototypeHelper methods, but to remote forms and links and the like. The concept is that you include `:remote => true` in your `form_for` or whatever helper methods support it, and then a driver called `rails.js` will look for those remotes and intercept the `submit` or `click` events and send them via xhr.

To use jquery you'll just need to replace the prototype ujs driver (which ships with rails) with the jquery ujs driver, that was extracted into its own repo shortly before the rails 3 beta release. You can find it [here](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/)

It can turn multiple javascript files into a single compressed js file.  It can even figure out which parts of the library you aren't using and remove them as well.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that. I already use a manual workflow that runs YUI Compressor and then CAT via a shell script. But I really just wondered if there was a built in Rails way or something to cut down on the http requests. Seems pointless to include so many non-minified versions as the default :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Rails 3, but I'll try to answer bonus question.

You can put whatever you want in public/javascript directory. By default it will load files: prototype.js, effects.js, dragdrop.js and controls.js ([read more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)). If you want to compress all js files and send it in one file, you can use this [plugin](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager).

Of course it won't work for dynamicaly generated js files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on that with trying to convert my old ajax with rails 3.

From what I can tell, they moved to a structure that adds a `data-remote=true` and when you add `:remote => true` to something like `link_to` which is supposed to replace `link_to_remote` in rails 3, so there are no more onclick methods that calls Ajax methods.

So, how does Ajax work in Rails 3, then? Well, you are supposed to have javascript methods that watch for when you click links that have a property of `data-remote=true` and does something with it, but don't actually include them in Rails (from what I can tell), it's library agnostic since you can write these methods to watch for clicks in prototype, jquery, write them yourself, or whatever else is out there.

I did find some javascript on github to get started that will watch for these events:

In [prototype](http://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs)

In [jQuery](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

I think in order to actually load jquery instead of prototype, you're going to have to just download it to `public/javascripts` and manually specify jquery, use `javascript_include_tag :all`, or override `javascript_include_tag` (not recommended)

Comment: I was wrong about Rails not including one of the UJS scripts.. it's in public/javascripts/rails.js I guess I just missed it before.